# Java failures in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[image]

[image]

I've attached two images to quickly display what I'm talking about.
It seems to effect my environment in incredibly annoying ways, such as no auto-complete for things like variables (every time I want to utilize a variable or parameter I have to literally type is every single time).

I tried restarting VSC, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling plugins. I also did a chkdsk for errors and corrected them but that seemed to have no correlation to the issues I've been having.

Interestingly enough I've also been having some other issues with my computer, such as my mail app not working anymore (it throws an error code), and not being able to connect to other microsoft products. Not sure if it's related but it seems to have began around the same time.

Answer (score 0):

- Reinstall the Java extension or update to a pre-release version.
- Press **CTRL + SHIFT + P**, and type `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace`. to clean up the workspace and restart vscode.

  [image]

Comment: Thank you very much good sir. I uninstalled redhat extension, which required me to uninstall the Java test runner as well. I did a restart and it worked! However I must add that when I reinstalled "Java language support" extension it was not loading, so I just kept that one uninstalled. Lastly I updated my JDK to 17, I'm just posting all the steps here in case anyone else runs into this random issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)